# Missing ARR Rewrite option in Failed Request Tracing

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, trace

I am using Application Request Routing 3.0 with IIS's failed request tracing. I am having issues with my rewrite rules so I wanted to troubleshoot it.

I wanted to follow the steps below to enable IIS logging of rewrite rules but the option doesn't seem to be there for me.

http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules

I am using Windows 2012 R2

[image]

Answer (score 18):

> If the Failed Request Tracing was installed after URL rewrite module,
>   the "Rewrite" area in Trace Providers may not be available. If you do
>   not see "Rewrite" area listed there, go to Add/Remove programs and
>   then run URL rewrite module installer in repair mode.

[Original source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules)

Comment: I couldn't find a repair mode. I just reinstalled the module and it worked

Comment: Go to Control Panel -> Programs and Features -> Select IIS URL Rwrite Module then click in "Repair" above

Answer (score 0):

TLDR: you can also just **reorder the FRT module to be listed BEFORE the urlrewrite module** in IIS.

This simpler solution may appeal to some, versus that ms-documented suggestion to just reinstall urlrewrite. You can go to the server level in iis, choose the "modules" feature, and use its "view ordered list" option. There you will see (in this scenario above) that the Failed request trace module is listed AFTER the urlrewrite module--reflecting the fact that FRT was enabled AFTER urlrewrite was installed. It's an easy situation to end up in, and many then never realize how much frt can help with tracking rewrite rules.

But rather than reinstall urlrewrite (the stock answer), you can just move the frt module to be before urlrewrite, using the options offered there to move modules up or down. (The steps to do that are well-documented by MS and others, so I'll not elaborate them here.)

This way, the frt feature is loaded first and this can watch/track rewrite processing--again achieving the same goal as the proposed uninstall/reinstall of urlrewrite.

Hope that helps some. Sadly, even a lot of resources on using FRT to help debug rewrite rules don't acknowledge this surprisingly common problem, let alone either solution here.

Comment: I tried your solution but it didn't work for me, even after restarting IIS through IIS Manager. Is there any step missing?

Comment: Are you saying that when you view your site in question, and visit the "modules" feature at that site level, and use the option to "view ordered list", the frt module is BEFORE the rewrite module? And yet when you view the failed request tracing feature (FOR THAT SITE), you don't see rewrite as an option in the UI?

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in the installation order of the IIS Trace Feature and the IIS Extensions that extend the built in Trace areas. If the IIS Trace feature is installed after the extensions that extend the trace areas, the new areas are not added.  This is because there is currently no detection or way to tell the Trace feature there are new items to add to the default list.

to add the missing areas, you can modify the Applicationhost.config file in: `%windir%\System32\inetsrv\config`

```
 <traceProviderDefinitions>
                    <add name="WWW Server" guid="{3a2a4e84-4c21-4981-ae10-3fda0d9b0f83}">
                        <areas>
                            <clear />
                            <add name="Authentication" value="2" />
                            <add name="Security" value="4" />
                            <add name="Filter" value="8" />
                            <add name="StaticFile" value="16" />
                            <add name="CGI" value="32" />
                            <add name="Compression" value="64" />
                            <add name="Cache" value="128" />
                            <add name="RequestNotifications" value="256" />
                            <add name="Module" value="512" />
                            <add name="FastCGI" value="4096" />
                            <add name="Rewrite" value="1024" />
                            <add name="RequestRouting" value="2048" />
                        </areas>
                    </add>

</traceProviderDefinitions>
```

or using Programs and Features find the Extension that is missing  trace areas, right click select REPAIR.